# How Can I Fix my HTML to display the text filed correctly as per screenshot?

Tags: html

This is how the output should look like:
[image: This is how the output should look like]

This is how my output is currently showing:
[image: This is how my output is currently showing]

Code : This is the code that is displaying [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC4cw.png)

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Service Options</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class ="col-md-3">   <input type="checkbox" name="includeInActive" value="true"
                    <%= if(isDefined(includeInActive) && includeInActive){ %> checked="checked" <% } %>
                    > 1-day Delivery
                </div>
                <div class ="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-start justify-content-between">

                    <label class = "pr-1">Fees</label>
                    <input type="number"  min="0" value = "0" step="any" />
                </div>
                <div class ="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-start justify-content-between">
                    <label class = "pr-1">Delivery Radius(Km)</label>
                    <input type="number"  min="0" value = "0" step="any" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your html uses classes from bootstrap, do you have bootstrap referenced on your html page?

Comment: 1. You should replace col-md-3 instead of col-md-4
2. You already use the **UI framework** on your web, so just use the specific HTML tag such as <Button> or <Model> of the UI framework which is including the CSS style ( that's why we use it ! )

Your code is putting original HTML tag ( <input> or <label> ), the framework can't recognize the tag in their own liberry, so just display as original

Answer (score 0):

You are using `col-md-3`'s within the `row` inside `col-md-9`

The columns are again divided into 12 within the `col-md-9`'s `row`

So use `col-md-4` on your inner divs

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Service Options</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class ="col-md-4">   <input type="checkbox" name="includeInActive" value="true"
                    <%= if(isDefined(includeInActive) && includeInActive){ %> checked="checked" <% } %>
                    > 1-day Delivery
                </div>
                <div class ="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-start justify-content-between">

                    <label class = "pr-1">Fees</label>
                    <input type="number"  min="0" value = "0" step="any" />
                </div>
                <div class ="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-start justify-content-between">
                    <label class = "pr-1">Delivery Radius(Km)</label>
                    <input type="number"  min="0" value = "0" step="any" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```